# Get bitmap and draw it into image

Tags: c#, image, graphics, bitmap, picturebox

I am trying to save my drawing from picturebox into bitmap and draw that bitmap into image. So far, nothing has appeared in the final image, but while debugging I can only say, that the original bitmap is not null and with/height are correct. However nothing appears after I draw it into image.

I save my drawing into bitmap like this:

```
GraphicsPath path = RoundedRectangle.Create(x, y, width, height, corners, RoundedRectangle.RectangleCorners.All);
        g.FillPath(Brushes.LightGray, path);


        g.SetClip(path);

        using (Font f = new Font("Tahoma", 9, FontStyle.Bold))
            g.DrawString(mtb_hotspotData.Text, f, Brushes.Black, textX, textY);
        g.ResetClip();

        bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, g);
```

Then save it:

```
hs.bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmap);
```

And finally use it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < imageSequence.Count; i++) {
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(imageSequence[i]);
            //g.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceOver;
            //hotspot.bitmap.MakeTransparent();
            int x = hotspot.coordinates[i].X;
            int y = hotspot.coordinates[i].Y;
            g.DrawImage(hotspot.bitmap, new Point(x, y));
        }


        return imageSequence;
```

So far I was not able to find any problem in this solution, therefore I have no idea, where the malfunction is.

Comment: where do you have those bits of code located?

Comment: There are two classes here. I draw and save graphics in first class (form for drawing) and the there is a class called hotspot where a store all the info about this bitmap (bitmap, X, Y).

Comment: It can be hard to find this sort of thing. If it was me I'd add some code to save the bitmaps to file in suitable places in your code, and then see if you can track down the silly. also minimise and maximise the window at various points, sometimes repaints aren't triggered where you would expect.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to save the bitmap into file. Also I shoud note, that after I draw bitmap into image, I generate avi video from that image (if that is changes something)

Comment: So when I save it, it is empty. Resolution is correct, size = 165 bytes, icon is black but when I open it, it is transparent. Problem (or one of them) is therefore in the proces of getting it from picturebox, right?

Comment: What is g __excatly__? How is it created? Are you creating the Bitmap __after__ you did the drawing???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand the relation of a `Bitmap` and a `Graphics` object.

- A `Graphics` object does **not contain** any graphics; it is a tool used to draw **into** a bitmap of some sort.
- The [Bitmap constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byca5y1f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you are using (`public Bitmap(int width, int height,   Graphics g)`) does **not** really **connect** the `Bitmap` and the `Graphics` object. It only uses the `dpi` resolution from the `Graphics`.

You don't show how your `Graphics` is created. If you want to draw into a `Bitmap` (as opposed to a control's surface) the most direct way is this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height);
bitmap.SetResolution(dpiX, dpiY);  // optional

using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap ))
{

   // do the drawing..
   // insert all your drawing code here!

}

// now the Bitmap can be saved or cloned..
bitmap.Save(..);
hs.bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmap);  // one way..
hs.bitmap = bitmap.Clone();      // ..or the other

// and finally disposed of (!!)
bitmap.Dispose();
```